# How truncate time while querying documents for date comparison in Cosmos Db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have document contains properties like this

```
{
    "id":"1bd13f8f-b56a-48cb-9b49-7fc4d88beeac",
    "name":"Sam",
    "createdOnDateTime": "2018-07-23T12:47:42.6407069Z"    
}
```

I want to query a document on basis of `createdOnDateTime` which is stored as string.

query e.g. -

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.createdOnDateTime>='2018-07-23' AND c.createdOnDateTime<='2018-07-23'
```

This will return all documents which are created on that day.

I am providing date value from date selector which gives only date without time so, it gives me problem while comparing date.

Is there any way to remove time from `createdOnDateTime` property or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The question is, what's wrong with changing your query date to use the ISO version? "2016-12-18T00:00:00.00000Z"

Answer (score 2):

CosmosDB clients are storing timestamps in [ISO8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and one of the good reasons to do so is that its [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) matches the flow of time. Meaning - you can sort and compare those strings and get them ordered by time they represent.

So in this case you don't need to remove time components just modify the passed in parameters to get the result you need. If you want all entries from entire date of `2018-07-23` then you can use query:

```
SELECT * FROM c 
WHERE c.createdOnDateTime >= '2018-07-23' 
  AND c.createdOnDateTime <  '2018-07-24'
```

Please note that this query can use a RANGE index on `createdOnDateTime`.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do this for grouping though? I'd like to group records by date without time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [User Defined Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) to implement your requirement, no need to update `createdOnDateTime` property.

***UDF：***

```
function con(date){
    var myDate = new Date(date);

    var month = myDate.getMonth()+1;
    if(month<10){
        month = "0"+month; 
    }
    return myDate.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+myDate.getDate();
}
```

***SQL：***

```
SELECT c.id,c.createdOnDateTime FROM c where udf.con(c.createdOnDateTime)>='2018-07-23' AND udf.con(c.createdOnDateTime)<='2018-07-23'
```

***Output :***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Note that going the udf way will block you from using index => sloooow full scan.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Get the database engine to do the work for you directly by storing your dates in ISO format, forget spending the extra cycles on developing or executing a UDF.